# Possible to use React's new Context API programmatically?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-state-management

I'm trying to have 1 big global state where I can perform actions, but I don't want all those actions to live in the same file.

I want to break actions out to their own files and abstract with a `changeState` function (like a reducer), but I'm not sure how to do this.

I have an example here. If you click the button, it will show you how far through the app it's gotten: https://codesandbox.io/s/r49qyymjzn

It seems to never hit the `{ctx => { console.log('...') }`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: is wrapping the changeName action into the Context.Consumer intended?

Comment: @ztadic91 Yeah, I ended up writing an entire global state management thing similar to Redux with it and sugared with lodash merge. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the `Context.Provider` as a stateful component. The action changeName needs to update the state of the `Context.Provider` class.

Changes in `context.js`

```
handleNameChange = changeName;


actions: {
  changeName: this.handleNameChange
}
```

changeName.js

```
export default (e, newName) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ name: newName });
};
```

Working sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rj0n6256l4)